# Animation on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I am trying to put animation in a UITableViewCell. Animation is that onClick table view cell change the frame of tableCell into tableview frame.

I have the following code:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell*cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell.frame.size.height == tableView.bounds.size.height){
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }else{
        cell.frame = tableView.bounds;
        [[cell superview] bringSubviewToFront:cell];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

It works fine but after change cell's frame I am able to tap another cells also which I don't want. How can I achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear, what do u mean by after change cell's frame I am able to tap another cells also ?

Comment: @vivekDas pls check 2nd image its my updated cell. I disabled table view scroll. if i tap again (suppose at bottom side) the cell (whic is not this one which is back side of this cell) tapped. Is it clear?

Comment: I used  [[cell superview] bringSubviewToFront:cell]; method to become selected cell overlay

Comment: So after overly cell what you want ? and how you will dismiss the overlay ?

Comment: @vivekDas I want if i tap again on  again open cell it should be refresh and it is working but other cells also in active which I don't want. I just want to intract with current cell

Comment: I am asking after one overlay cell how you want to dismiss the overlay ?

Comment: @vivekDas just want to reload tapped cell

Comment: you can have one variable called selectedIndex = -1 initially, then on selecting the cell set the value of this with the current cell selected index, so now if you select some other cell just check the selectedIndex value with the cell index if not equal just return don't do anything in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solution would be to declare a variable that will hold an array of indexPath of expanded cell like this

```
// Will hold the indexPath of expanded cell
var expandedCell : [IndexPath] = []
```

Second thing would be adding and removing the the cell that are/aren't expanded and to do that you have to update your UITableView Delegate `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let index = expandedCell.firstIndex { (localIndexPath) -> Bool in
        return indexPath == localIndexPath
    }
    if let index = index  {
        expandedCell.remove(at: index)
    } else {
        expandedCell.append(indexPath)
    }
    tableviewMessageList.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

And in the end you have to add another UITableView Delegate `heightForRowAt` to return the height of the cell if the cell's indexPath is in array it will return the expanded size else return the normal size of your cell like this:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if expandedCell.contains(indexPath) {
        return tableView.frame.height
    }
    return 200.0 //NormalHeight
}
```

> Note: My answer is in Swift but the same principle will apply for Objective-C you just need to change the Syntax.

Comment: This is not what I expect. sorry for delay. what I want I want disable unselected cell as per my code

Comment: your code just doing expend and collapse if am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I think a better approach to this would be to use a separate view to display the cell details full screen, although you may have some restrictions that require you to do it this way.  That being said, find my answer below.

### This is what I gather your current problem is:

You'd like to show the cell expanded, and when in that expanded state touches are going through the cell view and hitting the table view behind it and re-triggering `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` tableview delegate method (on other cells than the expanded one).

### These are a couple of the possible solutions I see:

1. Add a tap gesture recognizer to the cell when it's expanded so it will absorb the touch, then remove the gesture recognizer once it's consumed.

---

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnExpandedCell:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.frame = tableView.bounds;
    [[cell superview] bringSubviewToFront:cell];
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}

-(void)didTapOnExpandedCell:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
    // do whatever you were planning on doing when tapping on the
    // expanded cell
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [cell removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

2. Subclass UITableViewCell and override touchesBegan:

---

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    R4NTableViewCell *cell = (R4NTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.frame = tableView.bounds;
    [[cell superview] bringSubviewToFront:cell];
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}

// in R4NTableViewCell.m implementation override touchesBegan
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // if we're not selected, don't intercept the touch so the tableview can handle it
    // calling back to super will give the default tableview behavior and get our delegate callback
    if (self.selected == NO) {
        self.frameBeforeExpansion = self.frame;
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    } else { // we're in the expanded state so intercept the touch
        NSSet <UITouch *> *singleTouches = [[event allTouches] objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(UITouch * _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            return obj.tapCount == 1;
        }];
        if (singleTouches.count > 0) {
            // the user single tapped our view
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.7 initialSpringVelocity:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                self.frame = self.frameBeforeExpansion;
                [self.superview layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self setSelected:NO];
                self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

One additional thing I didn't really understand from your explanation (as the comments mentioned) is what you expect to happen when the user taps the expanded tableview cell.